# Setting delivery mode for AMQP (RabbitMQ)

Tags: php, queue, rabbitmq, amqp

[The docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpexchange.publish.php) say:

```
public bool AMQPExchange::publish ( string $message , string $routing_key [, int $params = 0 [, array $attributes ]] )
```

So I have this

```
 $this->exchange->publish(serialize($queue_message), $routing_key,AMQP_MANDATORY,array('delivery_mode' => '2'));
```

I'm trying to let the exchange KEEP TRYING to deliver the message?

Comment: I'm tryting to set the delivery mode: but i can't seem to get it right ??    ` $this->exchange->publish(serialize($queue_message), $routing_key,AMQP_MANDATORY,array('delivery_mode' => '2'));`

Comment: You should probably post your error as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell the exchange to keep trying to deliver your message.

Normally, the recipient of a message will either auto-ack the message, or they will ack the message after successfully processing it. I recommend the second of these two choices. If a message is not acked then it will be requeued and if there is more than one subscriber to the queue, then it is possible that a different subscriber will process it.

My experience is all with topic exchanges (where you implement fanouts by having multiple queues that subscribe to the same routing_key. I always used delivery_mode 2 and also declared the queues as durable.

If the queue does not exist before messages are published, then they will silently disappear.

I suspect that your problem is with the string `'2'`. Have you tried using the number `2` instead? Also it is a good idea to specify a content_type in the array as well. That would make it

```
$this->exchange->publish(serialize($queue_message),
            $routing_key,AMQP_MANDATORY,array('delivery_mode' => 2,
                                              'content_type' => 'text/json'));
```

Comment: Okey thanks :)
BUT HOW do I set the delivery_mode =2 the php docs are not quite clear I.e THE actual code